# Apply query criteria based on parameters

Tags: database, ms-access, filter, ms-access-forms

I need to run a query in a MS Access Database providing some parameters from a form. Imagine the next example:

I have a form which contains:

- CheckBox1 and Text1
- CheckBox2 and Text2
- Button (to run query)

Now imagine a query with two fields: `ID`, `NAME`.

I want to filter `ID` by Text1 only when CheckBox1 is enabled. If not, I want the query not to filter `ID` in any way (as if the 'query' input was empty).

In the same way, I want to filter `NAME` by Text2 only when CheckBox2 is enabled. If not, I want the query not to filter `NAME` in any way (just like `ID` before).

I've tried so many things for a couple of days and have sniffed tons of internet pages and still don't come up with a solution.

Comment: If you want to use dynamic parameterized query, edit question to show attempted query. Otherwise, use VBA to conditionally build filter criteria and apply to form or report. Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html. When you have code with specific issue, post question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a SQL query such as the following:

```sql
select * from YourTable t
where
    ([Forms]![YourForm]![CheckBox1] = False or t.ID   = [Forms]![YourForm]![Text1]) and
    ([Forms]![YourForm]![CheckBox2] = False or t.NAME = [Forms]![YourForm]![Text2])
```

(Change `YourTable` to the name of your table and `YourForm` to the name of your form; `t` is merely an alias so that you only have to change the table name in one place in the code).

Comment: Thank you so much! Have to say, when you enter this code and personalize it to 10 or 12 checkboxes, Access rewrites it as a savage extra-long code which makes everything crash. I've only been able to see the full code once and it is as if Access created a very redundant structure of `AND`s and `OR`s which ends up being thousands of lines of code. It can't handle that much lines and crashes.The problem with that is that you can't edit the original code you entered, because it's rewritten and impossible to understand, and because it crashes when you try to load it.

Comment: The solution to that is to only open the query in SQL code in Design mode (not to Access interface with field, criteria and all that). This way the code stays the way you wrote it. It is in the moment you exit SQL's environment when Access rewrites all the code. To access the results, I used a `List Box` object in a form, and used the query in the `Row Source` property. Hope it can help and prevent somebody from losing data when crashing!